# Integrate Flow player with EXTJS4

Tags: extjs, flowplayer

How to integrate flowplayer with EXTJS4

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
        <a href="http://path to video/flowplayer-960.mp4"  style="display:block;width:425px;height:300px;" id="player"/>                
        <script>
            flowplayer("player", "path to the swf location/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf",{clip:{autoPlay: false,autoBuffering: true}});         
        </script>

        <div id="player" style="display:block;width:425px;height:300px;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can embed every [html](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-html) code you want on a panel.

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Hello World Flowplayer',
    width: 200,
    html: '<script src="http://embed.flowplayer.org/5.2.1/embed.min.js"><div class="flowplayer" style="width: 624px; height: 260px;" data-origin="http://flowplayer.org/" data-analytics="UA-27182341-1" data-key="$437712314481272" data-rtmp="rtmp://s3b78u0kbtx79q.cloudfront.net/cfx/st"><video><source type="video/webm" src="http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.webm"><source type="video/mp4" src="http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.mp4"><source type="video/ogg" src="http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.ogv"><source type="video/flash" src="mp4:bauhaus/624x260.mp4"></video></div></script>',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```